# how can i upload laravel 5.5 project to free host?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5, laravel-authorization

I have made project with laravel 5.5 and when upload it to my website (free host)

I have this error

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
>
> (1/1) RuntimeException
>        The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths

I edited theses files

```
.env
index.php
config/app.php
config/database.php
```

and before i upload it i run this command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

after all of this still not working

any help plz ?

Comment: `i edit this files ` you edited those files, what did you do to those files in an attempt to fix the issue?

Comment: You need to make sure your server is running with php7 or higher for laravel 5.5

Comment: free host is running php7

Comment: @castis
index.php
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';

config/app.php
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://hedk.byethost3.com/signin/'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved with the following steps:-

edit config/app.php

change

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY'),
```

to
'key' => env('APP_KEY','mykey'),

mykey = key in .env file